# Reference for rigidity of higher rank action

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, group-actions

I heard some results about the rigidity of higher rank action and it looks very interesting. I would like to know if there are any good survey of paper to get started in this field. Thank you in advance !

Comment: This is a huge subject, probably a good spot to start digging is Brown's lecture notes and his recent ICM talk. 
 
If you are interested specifically in the current developments regarding Zimmer's conjecture (Brown-Fisher-Hurtado), you can consult Cantat's Bourbaki report from 2017.